# Can't set the background image of the UIView in swift: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value (lldb)

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

this is my code

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var timerLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var timerButton: UIButton!

    var timer : NSTimer?
    var ms = 0



    override func viewDidLoad() {

        timerLabel.text = "00:00"
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "background.png")!)
    }

    @IBAction func buttonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {

        if timerButton.currentTitle == "Stopp" {
            timer?.invalidate()
            timerButton.setTitle("Start", forState:UIControlState.Normal)
        } else {

            timerButton.setTitle("Stopp", forState:UIControlState.Normal)

            self.timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.01, target: self, selector: Selector("update"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        }
    }


    @IBAction func restartButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject){
        if timerLabel.text != "00:00" && ms != 0 {
            timer?.invalidate()
            timerLabel.text = "00:00"
            ms = 0
            timerButton.setTitle("Start", forState:UIControlState.Normal)
        }

    }


    func update() {
        self.ms++
        timerLabel.text = String(format: "%02d:%02d", ms / 100, ms % 100)

    }
}
```

I get this error:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
>   (lldb)

I dont know how to fix it. I would pleased if you could help me.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to access the value of a variable declared as an 'Implicitly Unwrapped Optional'. When such a variable turns nil it crashes. Please double check if your image exists.

Use image! if you're guaranteed that image? isn't nil else it crashes. I think in your case image is coming as nil and you are trying to force unwrap it.

You must do a nil check to avoid this crash.

```
UIImage *image = UIImage(named: "background.png");

if let image = image {
    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: image)
}
```

Comment: I uploaded the image in the folder "Supporting Files". With your adjustment I still get the error "Value of optional type 'UIImage?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'?". How can i fix this?

Comment: I've updated my post, please check. Basically, you need to ensure that UIImage object is not nil before force unwrapping it else it crashes.